# Sequences didn't restore from backup file

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a Postgres DB working alongside Django. Id in product model is:

---

id              | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('product_product_id_seq'::regclass)

I have exported it in .bak file and restored it in another server. now that id is like:

---

id              | integer                  |           | not null |

---

nextval does not appear in the second server. what is the problem?

**EDIT**

dump:

```
pg_dumpall db.bak
```

restore (in new server):

```
sudo -u postgres psql db < db.bak;
```

Comment: How exactly was the backup and restore done?

Comment: I have been updated the question

Comment: Hmm, neither the `pg_dumpall` nor the restore uses valid syntax. If you cannot remember exactly, try it again. Watch out for error messages. It should definitely restore everything.